# Can one use the 'permesso di soggiorno' to fly from Italy to Paris?

Tags: schengen, italy

Can one use the 'permesso di soggiorno' to fly from Italy to Paris? I'm planning just to visit Paris for 4 days.

Comment: Thank you but what I meant is that I'm do I need a valid passport or will the permesso di soggiorno is enough

Comment: You have to take your pass. Without it you can be denied boarding. Permesso di soggiorno is not an ID.

Answer (score 1):

You need a passport or passport-replacing travel document for this journey, in addition to your residence permit. If you are a refugee, you should use your refugee travel document «titolo di viaggio per stranieri» instead of a passport.